# Is it possible to crash entire computer from a buffer overflow by overwriting entire stack?

Tags: crash, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow

Is it possible to crash the computer by an extremely long buffer overflow?

This is more to understand the mechanics of the overflow than the actual consequences. Lets say I run a program without any buffer overflow protections. I keep overflowing and overwrite everything on the stack.

When the program instruction tries to return from the current call it returns an invalid address.

But all the values behind are also overwritten as well. The current program crashes and returns but other instruction pointers behind may be overwritten as well. Will this cause the entire computer/system to crash and cause any damages?

The source of my confusion is I don't know what happens after the process exits. The values of the stack will have been overwritten and unrecoverable, what are the consequences of that after the current process crashes and exits?

Thanks